# updatepanel.update is not updating

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using one updatepanel to do the partial update. This works well when I call the method UpdatePanel.Update and the Update mode is "Conditional".

This panel is not updating when there any required field validators are included in the page and they have some error. Can I update the updatepanel even there are some validation errors on the page.

Comment: update the question with your code and also which event you want to update the panel?

Comment: I have hidden field filed in the form and on a button click event of updatepanel, I will open a popup and call the __dopostback() method. This causes the post back of the page and hit the HiddenfieldforCallTax_ValueChanged event, where I am trying to update the update panel 'code' protected void HiddenfieldforCallTax_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {UpdatePanel updatePanelItems = panelTaxCaller.FindControl("UpdatePanelForItem") as UpdatePanel; BindItems(); // Rebinds the items in the Repeater which is in updatepanel which contains gridview
        updatePanelItems.Update(); 
    }

Answer (score 1):

Assign a same [**`validationGroup`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for all validators.

Comment: There are one problem here, there are 4 groups are performing the validation and they save different validationGroup set. But I can see the Server Side validations are not fired during the postback